# Razor Engine on Mono 3.2.x with Fast CGI - target specific .net?

Tags: razor, nginx, mono, servicestack, fastcgi

My site works on mono 2.10 and I'm nearly done on a brand new server upgrading to mono 3.2.x.

It works using XSP4, the ServiceStack Razor views render correctly. (And it fixes a lot of artefacts in  2.10)

When I set the site to use nginx + Fast CGI (4) however I get a HttpCompileException, caused by:

```
The predefined type `System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `mscorlib.dll'
```

Remember this works fine with xsp4 so I think it needs some setting to tie it to one .Net instance, maybe it's confused between .net 4.0 and .net 4.5? Any suggestions on how I can force it to use only one of these?

Note: I installed from git using latest (3.2.7), as the 3.2.5 release would crash. I'm using a clean Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. It didn't have mono on it before, and when I tried 3.2.5 it was another now deleted instance.

This is largely the same error as: [RazorEngine on Mono - TemplateCompilationException thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551661/razorengine-on-mono-templatecompilationexception-thrown)

But I had no other version installed. The build process added others which have since been deleted to no effect. All instances of mscorlib are here:

```
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: Just tried using XSP .webapp method instead of directly in case that cause it to work the same as XSP but no luck...

Comment: Apache works... so going with that for now. Must be some subtle config thing with Fast CGI.

Comment: Having the same issue here. Just one mono installed.

Comment: Apache works under FastCGI or are you using mod_mono? @Harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem is and was able to solve it.

The culprit are these files:
https://github.com/mono/xsp/tree/master/src/Mono.WebServer.FastCgi/Compatibility

For some reason, they added these compaibility classes that are compiled to a NET 4.0 target (which does not have the IReadOnlyList class), but when we run the fastcgi-mono-server4, it runs under the 4.5 runtime, which do have a IReadOnlyList class and therefore generates the Razor HttpCompile error.

The solution was adding these 2 parameters -d:NET_4_5 -sdk:4.5 to the Makefile.in of the FastCGI source project:

```
@NET_4_0_TRUE@  $(DMCS) -d:NET_2_0 -d:NET_4_0 -d:NET_4_5 -sdk:4.5 $(MCSFLAGS) $(references4) /out:$@ \
```

Then I recompiled and reinstalled with ./configure, make, make install and the Razor compile error was gone for good.

If you don't want to go through all this trouble, I'd recommend sticking to the latest released version of the xsp project, which didn't have these Compatibility classes.

Comment: Dema i didn't understand one thing, that change in parameters is on FastCGI mono server? If so, where did you get the source to modify it? I'm a little bit confused, i've mono 2.10 running with nginx and fastcgi and i'm looking to upgrade t 3.2x as well

Comment: I'm installing from git, and i've configured it again after alter the Makefile.in. However i get an error when i make it http://pastebin.com/BN03C4RX Do you have any idea?

Comment: Fixed, i had to do the same for Fpm Makefile.in

Comment: I'm glad you made it.